# ubuntu routing table with 3 NIC

Tags: ubuntu, routes

i want to configure ubuntu 12.04 as a router.
this ubuntu pc have 3 network cards

```
eth0:192.168.1.203 (LAN1)
eth1:172.16.30.21 (Internet)
eth2:10.216.1.107 (LAN2)
```

and

```
$ route -n

Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric   Ref  Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.30.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0        0    0   eth1
10.216.1.0      10.216.1.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0        0    0   eth2
10.216.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1        0    0   eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000     0    0   eth2
172.16.30.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1        0    0   eth1
192.168.0.0     192.168.1.3     255.255.0.0     UG    0        0    0   eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1        0    0   eth0
```

if i configure an other windows pc (PC1) like this :

```
ip:192.168.1.29
mask:255.255.255.0
gw:192.168.1.203
```

from this pc (PC1) i am connected to the internet and i can ping all IPs in this range  192.168.0.0/16 and this IP 10.216.1.107.but i cannot ping the other IPs in this range 10.216.1.0/24 (i can ping this range from ubuntu pc).

my problem is how to modify my route table to assure a connection between PC1 and all PCs in 10.216.1.0/24 range

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTbo4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The gateway does not need any special routes for this. Do the 10.216.1.0/24 systems have a route for 192.168.1.0/24 via the gateway (10.216.1.107)?